# What is the plural for timeout?

Tags: grammatical-number, orthography

In basketball, football, hockey, and many other sport the teams get a set number of timeouts.

I was watching a summer league NBA game and there were some stat nerds talking and one referenced that "timeouts" was the incorrect plural form for a timeout.  He said it should be times out.  This to me is nonsense and hits my ears bad but a few others agreed with him.  What is the plural of timeout?

Comment: http://grammarist.com/spelling/timeout-time-out/

Comment: What he said^. *Timeout* is the word, not *time out*. You should definitely trust yourself over the stats nerd(s).

Comment: I thought you would know better than to listen to stat nerds. Ask yourself this: is ‘times-out’ one of the many screw-ups perpetrated by stat nerds… or is it one of their many _screws-up_?

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet - If I can be fooled by some dude on ELU I can be fooled by some dude from the MIT.

Comment: After reading your question, what comes to my mind is the word "passerby." Its plural is passersby.  It think that's what the other person was trying to convince you; yet I don't know if this can be applied to the word "timeout," too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Information from Grammarist.com:

Timeout vs. time out
In American and Canadian English, timeout is one word in sports-related contexts, where it means an official pause in the action. *Timeouts is its plural*. In all other uses, time out is a two-word noun phrase.

I think the one guy was tweaking the other.  I can get a rise out of my husband insisting that "RBIs" (runs batted in) in baseball should be "RsBI."  It makes him crazy.  (This was answered in the EL&U question, "In baseball, is it proper to pluralize 'RBI'?")

Comment: The Grammarist page is not correct. _Timeout_ (as a count noun) is not generally considered incorrect in British English. The OED, which is thoroughly British, spells it _timeout_ in all countable uses, but has both _timeout_ and _time out_ as basically variants in non-count uses of the sports sense. In other words, you _call time out_, but you _take a timeout_. (The OED also gives _times out_ as a rare plural of _timeout_.)

Comment: I do like the use of "RsBI" though.  The next time we are having drinks after work I am going to have to convince my coworkers that it is truly RsBI and RBIs is purely for the incompetent layman.  Then I just sit back and listen to the fantasy baseball RsBI talk and giggle.

Comment: @Janus, the Grammarist quote refers to American and Canadian English.  I do take your point though, about "time out" in the sense of "The Raiders asked for a time out."  It would be two words in that sense, right?    Ryebread, wouldn't an English professor such as I know the correct pluralization of RBI?  lol  It drives people nuts.

Comment: @ewormuth I meant the part where it says that in British English _timeout_ would be considered incorrect—that's not right. Personally I would say (like the OED does) that the Raiders asked for _a timeout_; but to do so, they called _time out_. But I doubt there's anything very hard-and-fast about it.

Answer (score -2):

As RK01 referenced:

In sports it is *timeout*, and so the plural is *timeouts* -- in North America. In British English, it is two words, so the more correct plural is probably indeed *times out*, along the lines of *attorneys general*, where the second word is the modifier, not the noun.

The electronic and computer engineer term is also one word (timeout/timeouts).

Comment: The Grammarist page is not correct. _Timeout_ (as a count noun) is not generally considered incorrect in British English. The OED, which is thoroughly British, spells it _timeout_ in all countable uses, but has both _timeout_ and _time out_ as basically variants in non-count uses of the sports sense. In other words, you _call time out_, but you _take a timeout_.